# Optimal mod_rewrite regex. Does the way the matching patterns are arranged inside the regex matter?

Tags: mod-rewrite, optimization, regex

I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})?/load_page/([0-9]+)
```

Which arrangement would be optimal for the regex:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})?/load_page/([0-9]+)
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^/load_page/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})?/([0-9]+)
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})?/([0-9]+)/load_page
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think in your case there's a notable difference.

Want to be sure? Benchmark all of them with Apache Benchmark, Siege, JMeter or whatever benchmarking tool you want to use or are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Janne is likely right that the difference is negligible and that you should not optimize without benchmarking.

To answer the question anyway, it should depend on what URLs are requested. I would guess that most URLs requested don't have a path that starts with `/load_page`. In that case, it's likely that the regexp starting with `^/load_page` will be slightly faster because it can rule out many non-matching strings quickly by comparing the first few characters and not having to backtrack. So if you request `/foo`, it will compare the `f` to `l`, see a mismatch and bail after comparing one or two characters.

With the other regexps, it would see `/foo` and think "I'm seeing some fine alphanumerics" and only abort after realizing that the rest of the regexp doesn't match.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but wasn't sure if the URLs are matched left-to-right or right-to-left or if another algorithm is used. Probably best way to go would be to benchmark them

Comment: What little experience I have of implementing regexp engines, it was left-to-right.